# C++ struct as function argument vs. multiple const ref parameters vs. C++ core guidelines vs. performance?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-const-reference

I'm currently trying to decide whether to "structify" a rather long parameter set:

```
void fooCopy1(std::string const& source, std::string const& destination, std::string const& filter, std::string const& temp);
```

to this:

```
struct FooCopyArgs {
    std::string source;
    std::string destination;
    std::string filter;
    std::string temp;
};
void fooCopy2(FooCopyArgs const& args);
```

As already answered in two other questions:

- [C++ using struct arguments for functions instead of multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112338/c-using-struct-arguments-for-functions-instead-of-multiple-arguments)
- [Why pass structure to function instead of separate parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859201/why-pass-structure-to-function-instead-of-separate-parameters)

refactoring this could have several readability/maintainability **advantages**. For a bunch of these see the linked questions.

In *general* however I see one "big" problem with this approach in C++ specifically, and that is that the strings will always have to be copied before the call to this function, instead of using `const&` parameters.

This would be against [C++ Core Guideline F.16](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in) "pass cheaply-copied types by value and others by reference to const".

That is, non-cheap readonly parameters that would normally be passed by `const ref`, would need to be *copied* into the struct, which would be a general pessimization.

(Yes, the struct itself would be passed by const ref, but the struct data members would need to copied first.)

Example:

```
const string temp = ...;
const string filter = ...;
...
fooCopy2({"sourceItem", "targetItem", filter, temp});
```

For `"sourceItem"`, that is a locally defined parameter value, it would not matter.
However, for the passed down args `filter`and `temp` we would have an extraneous copy that could be avoided by the plain `const&` approach.

Disclaimer: Obviously, in 99% of cases the performance impact won't even be observable in the final application, but still it leaves a bad taste, esp. in the context of some such "fundamental" rule as F.16.

**Question** : Is there any clever way around this problem, that is:

- have a *safe* struct as parameter type (`const&` members are not safe; extremely prone to dangling references)
- avoid extraneous copy of non-cheap types
- keep composability if severeal functions use this pattern

---

Appendix: Why using `const&` members is unsafe:

```
struct HasConstRef {
    std::string const& member;
};

void f(HasConstRef const& arg) {
    std::cout << arg.member << "\n";
}

HasConstRef arg_producer() {
    HasConstRef result = { "there be dragons" };
    return result; // UB
}

void f_call() {
    f(arg_producer()); // *boom*, no diagnostic required
}
```

While I totally agree with the current answer that a const-ref-membered struct *can* be used correctly, it is also incredibly easy to use incorrectly without any help from the compiler. I would rather not do this.

I find that "hard to use incorrectly" is quite a long shot from "impossible to use incorrectly". And "normal" const-ref parameters, just like normal data members are hard-to-use-incorrectly (as far as C++ goes). `const& members` on the other hand are easy-to-use-incorrectly. Others seem to disagree: See the answer below. Alternatives still welcome.

Comment: Why copying? The strings might be stored as references or pointers in the struct as well. References rather, they are not optional anyway. One might need an appropriate constructor for.

Comment: If you are only ever passing one of these objects down the call stack (into a function) then having reference members is safe

Comment: @NathanOliver - yeah I know that it *can* be safe, but the struct and the whole thing would be extremely brittle and error prone without any compiler help.

Comment: @MartinBa What makes you think it's 'extremely brittle and error prone'? It's clearly documented in the class that these are references / non-null ptrs.

Comment: @MartinBa Can you explain what exactly do you mean by "extremely brittle and error prone"? What compiler help do you have in mind?

Comment: @KamilCuk - have provided example of why I find the const-ref-member solution too brittle.

Comment: "Appendix: Why using const& members is unsafe:" the only "safe" solution to the general issue to not use C++. Either you accept that c++ is not a safe language or not

Comment: @MartinBa Then just add a ctor to `HasConstRef` or use pointers. (Btw., `"there be dragons"` won't disappear when you exit `arg_producer()`, it exists till static destruction at minimum, but I can guess what you were thinking about - and even then, that's an issue of `arg_producer`).

Comment: I second lorro, you can always write a function the returns a dangling pointer / reference for any type. Thats not the fault of `HasConstRef`

Comment: This use case is safe, not brittle, and not error prone.

Answer (score 5):

Sooo why did you remove `const&`? The following compiles fine:

```
#include <string>
using string = std::string;
struct FooCopyArgs {
    std::string const& source;
    std::string const& destination;
    std::string const& filter;
    std::string const& temp;
};
void fooCopy2(FooCopyArgs const& args);
int main() {
    const string temp = "";
    const string filter = "";
    fooCopy2({"sourceItem", "targetItem", filter, temp});
}
```

Comment: OP's response when I pointed this out: *yeah I know that it can be safe, but the struct and the whole thing would be extremely brittle and error prone without any compiler help*

Comment: As soon as someone puts your `FooCopyArgsWithConstRef` version on the stack as a local variable it will break down. Without any compiler warnings.

Comment: This _is_ the solution; however, since references aren't making it AggregateType, sometimes it's preferred to use pointers (perhaps with a `non_null<std::string*>` annotation). That makes it easy to write `{&source, &destination, &filter, &temp}` if needed, therefore making this better. (Alternatively, you can add a ctor.)

Comment: `FooCopyArgsWithConstRef version on the stack as a local variable` I do not understand. Can you give an example? If you put `FooCopyArgs ` as a local variable in main, there is no difference, `{...}` creates a temporary anyway, it will be the same, just the lifetime of the variable will be veery slightly different.

Comment: @MartinBa Why do you think it breaks down? It's valid as long as the original args are valid. The only thing you don't have is extending the lifetime of a temporary at call (read: struct construction) point, but meh, if you do that, you need to be aware to put it in a variable.

Comment: 1+ for the nice fresh and juicy profile orange. It looks so delicious and matches the Stack Overflow colors so well.

Comment: Note: I will not downvote this as it has its uses. However, I will also not accept this as an answer as I deem it way too easy to misuse.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would worry less about performance, and more about semantics.  Items should be combined into a struct or class if they really belong together.  In other words, you want your classes and structs to have high cohesion.

Maybe `filter` and `temp` should be members of a class, and `fooCopy()` should be a member function in the same class.  Presumably, `filter` and `temp` do not change often, whereas `source` and `destination` do.

By the way, consider renaming `temp` to something more descriptive.